# Is “it is you that is wrong” correct?

Tags: subject-verb-agreement, relative-pronouns

I know that between *”it is you who are wrong”* and *”it is you who is wrong”*, the former is the correct version.

However, if I change **who** to **that**, is the same still true?

> It is you that are wrong. It is you that is wrong.

To me, **that are** is clearly wrong.

Answer (score 2):

This is a classic case of grammar where there are two completely different answers, one of which is "grammatically correct" and the other is "what everybody actually does".

To be grammatically correct, first, it's necessary to note that since "you" is a person, not a thing, the correct relative pronoun to use in this case is *always* "who".  You cannot actually use "that" in that sentence, as it is grammatically incorrect.  So the only technically correct way to say this is:

> It is you who are to blame.

(everything else is wrong)

If you follow that rule, it also avoids the whole secondary question of is/are entirely, so you're good.

However, that having been said, people *do* actually use "that" in this sort of sentence all the time.  So, according to the rules of grammar, if we accept "that" as being OK for now, the same subject-verb agreement rules would apply as for "who", so technically, the grammatically correct(ish) answer is that it should be:

> It is you that are to blame.

Except, again, the grammatically correct answer isn't what everybody actually does in practice.  To most native speakers, assuming that we're talking about a singular "you", that sentence would sound rather odd, and almost everybody would actually say:

> It is you that is to blame.

instead.

The reason for this, I believe, is a combination of the fact that the singular "you" is rather special (in that it uses "are" even when singular), and that "that" is more frequently/correctly used to refer to objects (which don't behave specially in this way), so in general people are used to saying "who are" (in the context of "you"), but people are more used to saying "that is" for anything singular.  As a result, when you mix "you" with "that", you get "you that is", because "that is" is the set phrase people are used to saying in general for anything singular.

So in summary, the most natural-sounding sentence is actually grammatically wrong in two separate ways, but it is still what most people say.  I guess this might actually be one of those cases where two wrongs do make a right..

Comment: "Who is wrong"? You or me? I believe it is you ||who is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

'That', in "It is you that are wrong", is a relative pronoun and it's not the subject of the subordinate clause. The real subject is 'you', so "are" is correct.

Comment: That sounds incredibly awkward to me.  Perhaps it's different between AmE and BrE?

Comment: @Andrew what would you make of it?

Comment: I'd probably say "It is you **who is** wrong", although if I thought about it, I'd probably correct myself and say "It is you **who are** wrong".  But using "that" I would always say "It is you **that's** wrong".  If I'm guilty of the typical American barbarism when it comes to English, then I feel bad, but nevertheless  ...

Comment: @Andrew Good to know it! I'm just a learner. All I addressed above in my answer is just based on the grammar rules I 've learnt from books. It could be plain wrong practically. So, feel free to correct me anytime. Thanks!

Comment: @Andrew As JeremyC pointed out, if 'you' refers to more than one person, would you still say: It is you that is wrong.?

Comment: @Andrew What about with other verbs except for 'to be'? E.g. It is you who has said that. VS It is you who have said that. which one is correct?

Comment: In truth, this phrasing is somewhat formal and stilted.  I would more likely say, *"You are the one who is wrong"* or *"You all are the ones who are wrong"* or just *"You (all) are wrong"*

Comment: Will it make sense if it is written as - 'It is you, that is wrong'?

Comment: I would pretty much never say "It is you who are wrong." I would say "It is you who is wrong."

Answer (score 0):

Who is wrong? If it is me, and nobody else, then I cannot for a moment see why you would not  say "It is you who is wrong."

If the people who **are** wrong are me and my whole family then you would say "It is you who **are** wrong".

The word "you" can be plural or singular depending on context. The verb following "who" must relate to whether the person or people being referred to are plural or singular.

I do not see any difference here between BrE and AmE.

Comment: So you mean the subject of the verb is in third person and the choice between **is/are** falls into singularity and plurality, right?

Comment: With the verb "to be" I recall that there is no subject as such, just a complement. Leaving that grammatical technicality aside, it all turns on whether "you" refers to one person or to more than one. If one person ,"is" is correct, if more than one ,"are".

Comment: But you never say: "you is wrong", no matter 'you' refers to one person or more than one. Maybe, the structure matters here?

Comment: What about with other verbs except for 'to be'? E.g. It is you who has said that. VS It is you who have said that. which one is correct?

Comment: @dan I agree with you. You have a point there. I think the same rule still applies.

Comment: "It is you who is wrong" is definitely not correct.  If the simple statement is "you are wrong", then you must use the same verb form in the rearranged version: "it is you who are wrong".  Singular/plural does not matter in this case because the second-person singular and plural of "to be" are both "are".

Answer (score 0):

Strictly  speaking It  is  you  who/ that  are  wrong  is the  correct  grammatical  form.

> **It  is  I  who  am to  blame**
>
> **It  is  you  who  are  to  blame**

Here  the  subjects  are  not  relative  pronouns  but  those  who  precede them.

> **So  it is  you  that  are  wrong** is  correct

I am  not  sure  whether  the  rule is  strictly  followed  in speech or  not.

In informal  contexts  we  hear  people  say **it  is  you  that  is  wrong**

Here  is  a link  which  shows  the  usage.

https://thegrammarexchange.infopop.cc/topic/i-who-am-is-to-blame

Comment: You is plural or singular in English.